# Пространство имен CSS 3

Tags: css

имеется такой код на CSS GRID

```
.test {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
        .filter {
            grid-row: 1 / span 3;
        }
        .test div {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 50px;
        }
```

Как видно у класса .filter есть свойство `grid-row: 1 / span 3;` для чего нужно это самое span? и может ли этот span называться например `proverka?`

Comment: в данном случае `span` является ключевым словом

Comment: Для чего нужны эти самые ключевые слова?

Comment: по разному будут располагаться элементы https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column

Comment: ключевое слово может быть любым?

Comment: ключевое оно потому и ключевое, что заранее задано :-)